# how to preserve value in each function call without global,self, in python

Tags: python

This question is get asked in interview,
define function that should satisfy 3 cases

```
case 1:set initial balance
case 2:deduct the amount and return balance
case 3:should add amount to balance and return current balance
```

conditions:
1.do not use global variable 
2.do not use self(means without class)
3.do not use file or something like that

so i defined function like,

```
def fun1(amt,reset=None):
    if reset:
            fun1.balance = reset
    fun1.balance = fun1.balance-amt
    return fun1.balance

print fun1(0,500)#will set balance 500
print fun1(200) #will deduct amount 200 and return balance 300
print fun1(0,400)#should add 400 to balance and return 700
```

soo i want to preserver value of balance at every function call
in above case 
fun1(0,500)
fun1(200) works well
but how to modified the code to third case fun1(0,400) return true result

was stuck in third case which will update balance...

Comment: Maybe with a mutable default argument - but it would be ugly.

Comment: It seems you must use the `global` statement in your function.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code it, but could you use a closure some how?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. For the amount, use negative number to deduct and positive number to add. You can also use zero to query the balance:

```
def transact(amount, reset=None):
    if reset:
        transact.balance = reset
    transact.balance = transact.balance + amount
    return transact.balance

print transact(0, 500) # will set balance 500
print transact(-200)   # will deduct amount 200 and return balance 300
print transact(400)    # add 400 to make 700
```

I am not sure if this is what the interviewer has in mind, but it works.

Comment: i used exception handling bellow posted answer

Answer (score 0):

i used exception handling

```
def fun1(amt,reset=None):
    if reset:
        try:
            fun1.balance += reset
        except:
            fun1.balance = reset

    fun1.balance = fun1.balance-amt
    return fun1.balance
```

now it works fine but dont know how much feasible...

```
print fun1(0,500)#will set balance 500
print fun1(200) #will deduct amount 200 and return balance 300
print fun1(0,400)#should add 400 to balance and return 700
```

~